# how to resolve this errors ? i can not run it so i dont know?

Tags: java, android, xml, styles, breakout

i want to resolve my mistake pls help me

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@Color/ColorPrimary</item>

        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@Color/ColorAccent</item>

    </style>
```

android say:
Error:(9, 34) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'colorAccent' with value '@Color/ColorAccent').

Comment: Can you please colors.xml file in here?

Comment: no i cant sorry ,but  another code have not mistake , im sure

Comment: Can you change it from Color to color and see if that resolve

Comment: i do it but again make error......  :(

Comment: Is there a color present with the name 'ColorAccent' with the same case in color.xml, that it should be ColorAccent and not colorAccent.

Answer (score 1):

Check where the name id present in colors.xml and with the proper case sensitivity and spelling as the one which you mentioned in the style file.

Answer (score 0):

Xml cannot allow capitalization. So the file name should be `color` and not `Color`
Be careful with cases. Attributes are like variables, start with small letters.

Show us your colors.xml

Answer (score 0):

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/ColorAccent</item>
    </style>
<style name="Button_style" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:textSize">25sp</item>
        <item name="android:background">#ffffad2f</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#fff</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

ok,i did 
 so what is the problem again ?